# Launch android application from link in sms

Tags: android, xml

I have read all the other posts on doing this but none have solved my problem. Obviously the scheme has to be http for the link otherwise it is not clickable in the sms.

if I use what others have posted and i click on an http link i get offered:

open url, add to bookmarks, copy message text

if I open the URL, I just get the option to choose a browser, nothing else.

I need it to open the application, not give browser options.

Please help.

XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.catagory.DEFAULT"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.catagory.BROWSABLE"/>    
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="starttestapp.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: from android docs: `Note: scheme matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive, unlike the RFC. As a result, you should always specify schemes using lowercase letters.` .... and you have `android:scheme="Http"` anyway ... it will always ask about app to run unless user select default action ...

Comment: changed it and still does not open app or give the option to open app

Comment: hmm it works (with small http/https) for me at least on SGS2 and 2.3.3 emu

Comment: I tried on my SGS2 and SGS3

Comment: I even host a page with :  

<a href="http://starttestapp.com">Download our App!</a>

and that didn't work when clicked on

Comment: it have to be installed first ... so it you wana tell user in sms that she/he should install your app you should provide url to your apk file or Play Store's link to your app

Comment: @David: By doing it this way, it still shows the option of Browser right? Is there a way in which in only opens my app directly without giving the option of browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy pasted your code, then you have a spelling error:

catagory should be category like this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```